# EventHandler Invoking question

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to invoke the below but the EventHander is not compatible with the RasConnectionEventArgs from my calling event, how would I invoke SetOverlayIcon and my notification icon on the UI thread?

```
Public Sub watcher_Connected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RasConnectionEventArgs)

    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf OnRegChanged))
    Else

        TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(My.Resources.LockIcon, "Connected")
        Me.NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Connected", e.Connection.EntryName, ToolTipIcon.Info)

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Winn's response to your support request:

> The RasConnectionWatcher class is
>   multi-threaded, as such you just need
>   to set the SynchronizingObject
>   property on the component. If you have
>   the component on a form, you can set
>   it to the form instance. It will
>   handle the thread synchronization for
>   you automatically once it's been set.

Or do it similar to this:

```
    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(Of RasConnectionEventArgs)(AddressOf watcher_Connected), sender, e)
    Else
        '' etc...
    End If
```

I'm guessing at the delegate type name.

Comment: Hi Hans, I checked the documentation for any event handlers, nothing obvious. I've attached a pic of the available.

Comment: Make it New EventHandler(Of RasConnectionEventArgs)(AddressOf watcher_Connected)

Comment: Some of the components have documentation about the property, I'll make sure the rest of the components do as well for the upcoming 1.2 release. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Missed the thread sync object: watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me

http://dotras.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=232088